# Joining entries with the same ID of an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the following array of objects:

```
[{
"JobPosition": [
    {
    "node": {
        "jobTitle": "Front end",
        "jobLocation": "LOCATION: London",
        "jobTest": {
        "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS__us"
        }
    }
    },
    {
    "node": {
        "jobTitle": "Back end developer",
        "jobLocation": "LOCATION: Milan ",
        "jobTest": {
        "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___it"
        }
    }
    },
    {
    "node": {
        "jobTitle": "Android Developer",
        "jobLocation": "LOCATION: London",
        "jobTest": {
        "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___de"
        }
    }
    }
]},
{
"JobsPage": [
    {
        "node": {
        "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS__us",
        "pageName": "Job",
        "seoTitle": "Jobs",
        "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
        "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___it",
        "pageName": "Job",
        "seoTitle": "Work with us",
        "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
        }
    },
    {
        "node": {
        "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___de",
        "pageName": "Job",
        "seoTitle": "Jobs",
        "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
        "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
        }
    }]
}]
```

I need to join the entries with the same ID and add a key for the language, in order to achieve this data structure:

```
[{
    "us": [{
            "node": {
                "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS__us",
                "pageName": "Job",
                "seoTitle": "Jobs",
                "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
                "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "jobTitle": "iOS Mobile Developer",
                "jobLocation": "LOCATION: MILANO (IT)",
                "jobTest": {
                    "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS__us"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}, {
    "it": [{
            "node": {
                "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___it",
                "pageName": "Job",
                "seoTitle": "Lavora con noi",
                "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
                "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "jobTitle": "Front End",
                "jobLocation": "LOCATION: MILANO (IT)",
                "jobTest": {
                    "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___it"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}, {
    "de": [{
            "node": {
                "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___de",
                "pageName": "Job",
                "seoTitle": "Lavora con noi",
                "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
                "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        },
        {
            "node": {
                "jobTitle": "Back end developer",
                "jobLocation": "LOCATION: Milan",
                "jobTest": {
                    "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___de"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

I only managed to join everything in a single object, any ideas how to get this done in javascript? maybe the filter and reduce methods might help but i am pretty new to it. Thanks

Comment: Is there supposed to be an array wrapped around those two input objects?  (Overall, your indentation makes this hard to understand.)

Comment: yes there is an array wrapping those 2 input object, just edited the code

Comment: What did you try? Post the code, please.

Comment: Since the `id` field you need to manipulate to fetch the country lies in different places in the two objects above, there is little reason to combine them into a single one unless that's how the data is already structured.  I would expect to work with `input[0].JobPostiion` and `input[1].JobsPage` separately, then combine those results.

Answer (score 0):

`Array.reduce()` + `Array.map()` solution:

```js
var data = [{ "JobPosition": [ { "node": { "jobTitle": "iOS Mobile Developer", "jobLocation": "LOCATION: MILANO (IT)", "jobTest": { "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS__us" } } }, { "node": { "jobTitle": "Android Mobile Developer - IT", "jobLocation": "LOCATION: MILANO (IT)", "jobTest": { "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___it" } } }, { "node": { "jobTitle": "Android Mobile Developer - DE", "jobLocation": "LOCATION: MILANO (IT)", "jobTest": { "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___de" } } } ]}, 
            { "JobsPage": [ { "node": { "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS__us", "pageName": "Job", "seoTitle": "Jobs", "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum", "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum", } }, { "node": { "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___it", "pageName": "Job", "seoTitle": "Lavora con noi", "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum", "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum", } }, { "node": { "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___de", "pageName": "Job", "seoTitle": "Jobs", "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum", "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum", } }] }
],
groups = data[0].JobPosition.concat(data[1].JobsPage).reduce(function(r, o){
    var cc = (o.node.id || o.node.jobTest.id).substr(-2);  // extracting country code
    (r[cc])? r[cc].push(o) : r[cc] = [o];
    return r;
}, {}),

result = Object.keys(groups).map(function(k){
    var o = {};
    o[k] = groups[k];
    return o;
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using map and filter, I added a JSON.stringify to help you to see the result better:

```js
var jobsInformation = [{
    "JobPosition": [
        {
        "node": {
            "jobTitle": "iOS Mobile Developer",
            "jobLocation": "LOCATION: MILANO (IT)",
            "jobTest": {
            "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS__us"
            }
        }
        },
        {
        "node": {
            "jobTitle": "Android Mobile Developer - IT",
            "jobLocation": "LOCATION: MILANO (IT)",
            "jobTest": {
            "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___it"
            }
        }
        },
        {
        "node": {
            "jobTitle": "Android Mobile Developer - DE",
            "jobLocation": "LOCATION: MILANO (IT)",
            "jobTest": {
            "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___de"
            }
        }
        }
    ]},
    {
    "JobsPage": [
        {
            "node": {
            "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS__us",
            "pageName": "Job",
            "seoTitle": "Jobs",
            "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        },
        {
            "node": {
            "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___it",
            "pageName": "Job",
            "seoTitle": "Lavora con noi",
            "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        },
        {
            "node": {
            "id": "c3FDAuPSTfqIkIUi6qcOmqS___de",
            "pageName": "Job",
            "seoTitle": "Jobs",
            "seoDescription": "Lorem Ipsum",
            "seoKeywords": "Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum, Lorem Ipsum",
            }
        }]
    }]

const jobsPosition = jobsInformation[0]['JobPosition']
const jobsPage = jobsInformation[1]['JobsPage']

const jobs = jobsPosition.map(jobPosition => {
    const id = jobPosition.node.jobTest.id;
    const country = id.split('__')[1];

    const jobMatches = jobsPage.filter(jobPage => jobPage.node.id === id);
    const jobMatch = jobMatches[0];

    return {
        [country]: [
            jobPosition,
            jobMatch
        ]
    }
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(jobs, null, ' ', 3));
```